# iPhone 5S cases compatible with Touch ID

Tags: case, iphone

Can anyone recommend iPhone 5S cases that work well with the finger-print scanner? I know the cases Apple sells are compatible, but any others would be great. Please suggest with links. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point why a normal iPhone 5 case not work for you as the physical dimensioning for both of them is same and the TouchID is on the Home Button and no Case in general covers that, So all the cases compatible with iPhone 5 will be compatible with iPhone 5S.

Comment: I have a iPhone 5 case that hinders the touch ID. Its a little too thick around the home-button.

Comment: As I said most of the cases this thing is true, in specific situations you may have to buy a new case.
You can see the discussion on the Apple Store page http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/iphone/will-the-iphone-5s-fit-in-standard-iphone-5-cases/QUCXTK4U2C4KAYFT9

Comment: So you do see my point now. lol

Comment: I get you point, what I wanted to say was that a normal case for iPhone 5 can be used for iPhone 5S as well.

Comment: @killswitch "all the cases compatible with the iPhone 5 will be compatible with the iPhone 5S" Define "compatible" ... because there is now a larger dual flash area and a touchID home button that needs a bit more space around the edge for finger detection. While the 5S will fit in the same case physically, several cases do not have the appropriate spacing for one or both. So, the question by OP is very valid. Who wants to be the guinea pig on an expensive case, to find out it blocks part of the flash or touchID?

Comment: A simple google search will show you almost all the cases available for iPhone 5 and 5S, the problem encountered is not with the flash for anyone, some people thought have troubles with touch id and that's what my answer said, almost all cases will be compatible but a few which interfere with the touch id scanning.